# c# getting a list from a field out of a list

Tags: c#, .net, list, foreach

I'm sorry about the confusing title, but I didnt find a better way to explain my issue.

I have a list of objects, `myList`, lets call them `MyObject`. the objects look something like this:

```
Class MyObject
{
    int MYInt{get;set;}
    string MYString{get;set;}
}

List<MyObject> myList;
...
```

I am looking for a nice/short/fancy way to create a `List<string>` from `myList`, where I am using only the `MyString` property.

I can do this using `myList.forEach()`, but I was wondering if there's a nicer way

Thanks!!

Answer (score 20):

With LINQ:

```
var list = myList.Select(o => o.MYString);
```

That returns an `IEnumerable<string>`. To get a `List<string>` simply add a call to `ToList()`:

```
var list = myList.Select(o => o.MYString).ToList();
```

Then iterate over the results as you normally would:

```
foreach (string s in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that if all you want to do is iterate over it, you don’t need `ToList()`. Use that only if you need to modify the new list or index into it.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need for LINQ if your input and output lists are both [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx). You can use the [`ConvertAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf.aspx) method instead:

```
List<string> listOfStrings = myList.ConvertAll(o => o.MYString);
```

Comment: well, in my case, the input and output are not the same. input is List<MyObject> and output is List<string>. will convertAll() still work?

Comment: What is “there is no need for LINQ” supposed to mean? It’s not like LINQ is a whole separate library or anything, you know. Whether you use `.ConvertAll` or `.Select` makes no practical difference.

Comment: @Timwi: It means exactly what it says: using LINQ isn't the only possible solution; `ConvertAll` is another alternative. In fact, `ConvertAll` will be slightly more efficient than LINQ because *(a)* it can copy the data using direct array access rather than needing to instantiate and repeatedly call iterators, and *(b)*  it can allocate the destination list to the correct size at the outset rather than dynamically resizing as it goes. (But, as you say, this small performance benefit makes no practical difference in *most* real-world situations.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's [Ahmad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622751/c-getting-a-list-from-a-field-out-of-a-list/3622762#3622762) using integrated query syntax:

```
var strings = from x in myList
              select x.MYString;

List<string> list = strings.ToList();
```

This could also be written:

```
List<string> list = (from x in myList
                     select x.MYString).ToList();
```